# How to add z index to canvas.drawImage in js (I want to display myImages always at the top)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can we add z index to drawImage in javaScript ??? if we add can you explain??

```
function drawCanvas(time, myClass, myImages, context) {
    drawImageWithCenter(myClass.bgImage, 512, 384);
    var indx;
    for (indx=0; indx < 5; indx++){
        if(a[indx] == false){
            drawImageWithCenter(
                myClass.rightImage, tickX[indx], tickY[indx]);
        }
    }
    for (indx=0; indx < myImages.length; indx++)
    {
        if(myImages[indx].isVisible){
            drawImageWithCenter(myImages[indx].img[myImages[indx].currentFrame],myImages[indx].imgX,myImages[indx].imgY);
        }
    }

    if(spoted==5 && B_end==true){
        drawImageWithCenter(myClass.endPopup, 512, 384);
    }
    context.font = "30px Gill Sans";
    drawCenterText("Spot the 5 differences in the pictures on the right...", 150, 80);
    drawCenterText("Score: " + spoted, 30, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is not concept of z-index in canvas. Objects, that are drawn later in the code will overdraw everything that was drawn earlier.

If you need to control z-index, you must manage this in your code. For example, you can store images in array of objects, and each item will have it's own z-index property. Before you draw your images in loop, just sort the array by it's item's z-index.

Comment: I agree with @Mako that there isn't a zIndex "within" a canvas. But, there is "on" a canvas. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

1) Use multiple canvas elements, one for each layer you need.
2) Set zIndex as appropriate for each canvas.

```
<yourCanvasElement>.style.zIndex = 5;
```

**[See this as a reference](http://html5.litten.com/layers/canvaslayers.html)**